# PHP Extension intl permission on macOS

Tags: php, macos, permissions, macos-sierra, intl

I installed `PHP` extension `INTL` using `Homebrew`.

This is my code to test it

```
if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
    die('SUCCESS! The intl extension is enabled!');
} else {
    die('OOPS! The intl extension is not enabled!');
}
```

In `CLI` after executing this code I get `SUCCESS! The intl extension is enabled!`

But in browser `OOPS! The intl extension is not enabled!`

I think it might be a permission problem. I don't use `MAMP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you edited **all** `php.ini` used. In most distros cli, HTTPd module and CGI version have **separate** `php.ini` file. Simplest way to deal with it is to run

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and check what `php.ini` it points to. And then edit as needed.

> I think it might be a permission problem

httpd's error log as good start to confirm that, yet don't think it's the culprit in your case.